# Running an nginx forward proxy in kubernetes, getting connection timeout

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, proxy, istio

I am trying to run a nginx forward proxy in kubernetes but I'm facing some issues.

My configuration:

- nginx configured as forward proxy with http connect module, running on docker: [Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/Chm11vGb) - listens to 8888
- K8S with istio 1.4 [Deployment, service, gateway and virtual service configuration](https://pastebin.com/VX7M9mRM), host exposed to 36088
- Firefox for testing

My steps:

1. For local testing, I'm configuring the connection settings in [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox) to point to the instance of nginx running in Docker on `localhost:8888`. With this configuration, the proxy is behaving as expected, denying and allowing traffic as per the `nginx.conf`.
2. For testing my pod in K8S, I can run `kubectl port-forward name-of-my-pod 8888:8080` and configure Firefox to use the proxy forwarded on `localhost:8080`. As per point 1, the proxy works as expected and I can see the traffic hitting my pod in the logs.
3. Finally, To test my istio/AKS configuration, I can hit `https://proxy.mydomain.net:36088` (defined in the gatwway) with a web browser. The url responds just fine and I can see the pod outputting some logs.

Sadly, though, when I configure Firefox to make use of `proxy.mydomain.net:36088`, I am getting `connection timeout` and I can see that the traffic is not actually hitting my pod and I am not getting any logs.

In other words, the proxy doesn't seem to be working when I use it as a proxy, but it responds fine when I access its URL a normal website.

Based on the fact that the traffic doesn't seem to hit my pod, I guess that I need to configure something else in istio/aks to ensure that my service/pod works as a proxy, but I don't know if my guess is right. Is anything obvious that am I missing?

Comment: Hello. Have you tried to expose your proxy directly with service of type `LoadBalancer` (without `Istio`)? Have you managed to make it work in this way? It could shed some light where the actual issue lies depending if it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of digging, we managed to make this work.

This is how our templates look like: [deployment, gateway, service and virtualservice](https://pastebin.com/xUE4msF5)

The crucial point was:

- Adding the `.Values.istio.port.number` to the istio-ingressgateway
- configuring `.Values.istio.port.protocol` to TCP
- configuring the gateway as `PASSTHROUGH`